# Requirejs baseUrl to prepend only bower modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, bower

Here's my directory structure

- /assets

  - /javascripts

    - /config.js
- /bower_components
- /gruntfile.js

Here's my rjs options

```
{
    name: "config",
    mainConfigFile: "assets/javascripts/config.js",
    out: "public/main.js"
}
```

Here's my config.js file

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "../../bower_components",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery/jquery",
    }
});
```

It's asking for `bower_components/config.js`... which isn't right.

I want it to look for modules in both directories, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout browserify or webpack they can do this easily.

- http://browserify.org/
- https://webpack.github.io/